# Looking for tutorial resources on basic, non-macro assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Are there any resources on x86 32/64-bit assembly programming without macros? The only one I found so far, and I've searched for months, is the "Assembly Primer for Hackers" on Securitytube. So far I've wrote programs in C and disassembled them to learn about the flow.

Please don't misunderstand me, I've read all the common resources you can find on Google (except the Intel manuals itself) and all use macros instead of pushing parameters.

There is just no sense in learning assembly with high level structures, since it almost doesn't differ from C. The sole purpose of learning low level assembly for me is to obtain practical knowledge how the machine itself works on its fundamental levels and how to control it.

Comment: Wow, I forgot all about assembler macros.  Hah.  So what kind of reference are you hoping for?  Just a straight-up opcode reference?  Or like an introduction to practical application development on x86?  It strikes me that in the modern world there is no such thing as practical application development in any machine language.

Comment: Most modern assemblers more-or-less support macros anyway. But all of them let you do calls and ifelses harder way. I do not know, which materials have you already gone through, but I'd suggest that read about FASM. It has decent set of materials/tutorials/examples both with and without using macros on their homepage.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572818/best-book-to-learn-windows-assembly-programming

Comment: Thanks, I've read the MASM32 tutorials and a some of the NASM tutorials so far, but all of them use macros since they want to find a balance between low-level and productivity (which I don't care about). I wasn't aware of FASM, I will investigate. The "Under the hood article is good" but the rest is crap. Especially, HLA which is exactly the type of thing I don't want. The "x86 32-bit assembly for Atheists" is also a good starting point, but doesn't go far enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a basic, (almost) non-macro based intro see [this](http://siyobik.info/main/documents/view/x86-tutorial/) ([this](http://www.freebyte.com/programming/assembler/#onlineassemblytutorials) should be of use too, unfortunatly some of the good links are dead). the problem with you question is that most people writing stuff in asm will use a macro assembler, so finding tutorials that don't use it can be very tricky. the best place actually would be reverse engineering tutorials, such as [this generic one](http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/152/2/), as you don't use a macro assembler for dissassembly :P

for more advanced low level x86 assembly, check out [Dr Agner Fogs Optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) (volume 2 specifically).

Comment: I think this is the best answer there is. If I gain the knowledge I seek, I will share it...